# how to overload the css style of a visual component [library]?

Tags: css, angular

With Angular 6,

I created a multi-project workspace.

This workspace contains:

- libraries (visual component)
- business projects

**My problem :**
In a project, I call / use a library (visual component) and I need to change the look and feel of the visual component.

Here is a simple example:

Angular Project 1:

> library.html

```
<div class="myclass">Visual component</div>
```

> library.css

```
.myclass {
   color: red;
}
```

> library.ts

```
...
@component ({
   selector: 'compolabel',
   templateUrl: './library.html',
   styleUrls: ['./library.css']
})
...
```

Angular Project 2:

> application.html

```
<compolabel></compolabel>
```

> application.css

```
.myclass {
   color: blue;
}

/* this does not work
:: ng-deep .myclass {
   color: blue;
} */
```

> application.ts

```
...
```

**My question:**

I would like the color of the text to be **blue**.

**How can I do ? What is the right method?**

Comment: You can use an Attribute Directive: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: Have you tried to add !important ? For example:  color: blue !important;

Comment: I am looking for a CSS solution or an Angular practice to set up.

Your two solutions do not suit me.

1- I want to change a color, a size, a complete layout ... without going through html code.

2- !important is not a correct use.

Comment: I am looking for a CSS solution or an Angular practice to set up.

Your two solutions do not suit me.

1- I want to change a color, a size, a complete layout ... without going through html code.

2- !important is not a correct use.